# How to print from android web browser to Bluetooth thermal printer?

Tags: javascript, android, asp.net-mvc, printing

I'm using the Asp.Net MVC application to print the invoice to a Bluetooth printer from a web browser.

Can anyone help with this, I have an invoice page and when the user clicks the print button I want to show all the printer over the network line and connected the printer with Bluetooth where the user can select a printer and give the print command.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible on ASP.NET MVC alone because it is done on the server-side. To print on Android, you can do this using the Bluetooth adapter.
My idea for printing on ASP.NET is to get the invoice as a string in javascript and print it.

```
var printWindow = window.open();
  printWindow.document.open('text/plain')
  printWindow.document.write(zpl);
  printWindow.document.close();
  printWindow.focus();
  printWindow.print();
  printWindow.close();
```

Comment: Is It Possible with MVC and Javascript? If Yes. Then How?

Comment: You will be able to print using JavaScript. If you can set your invoice output as PartialView, convert the values ​​to a string with a function and receive it on the user side. And finally, you can print it.